# How to use quotation marks in java REST

Tags: java, string, rest, escaping

I know that in java when you wish to use quotation marks in a string you should do something like this: `private String quotationMarks = "\"";`
It's all great when working in eclipse - but here is the thing: I have a method that returns a string - with quotation marks in it; and when I invoke this method by REST (curl) I see the back-slash as well. Say my method returned the following string: `what a good "day"` - then when I invoke this method by curl - I get `what a great \"day\"` and that's not good for me.
Why is that and how can I avoid this back-slash to be returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the **key-value in JSON are double-quoted in format** {"text":"what a good day"}. So, if there is already a quoted string in value, the json builder library you are using will automatically add escape charater before double quotes.
Eg. in your case

> {"text":"what a good \"day\""} - valid json
>
> {"text":"what a good "day""} - invalid json

You can check validity of your json at [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/)